# Can not push files to GIT

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I am new to git and been messing around with it (creating, deleting,  repositories, heads, projects, etc) to learn it, I understand how to add to items to the staging area and commit them, but when I try to push a file called P18.MovieApp from my computer to git to upload it, it gives me this error:

```
$ git push P18.MovieApp/
fatal: 'P18.MovieApp/' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

(During my time with git, I have created and deleted multiple repositories and maybe have messed something up).

Another weird message I get when I type "git status" and I can not get rid of,  is this:

```
On branch main
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
        modified:   playground/CODE/mypage2 (modified content, untracked content)
```

I have this file mypage2 (there used to be a file gitignore in, I deleted it manually). I tried to get rid of this message by using git add/ git restore/ git rm, but I can not manage. As If I did not have rights to do it or file could not be read? I am very confused with Git, so now all I can do is to upload my files manually to Github....

Comment: Have a look at how to [push commits to a remote repository](https://docs.github.com/en/github/using-git/pushing-commits-to-a-remote-repository).

Comment: You don't push files, you push commits. `gits status` is very insightful here; you need to `git add <file>` as very first step.

Comment: I have done it. I added the file, then committed file successfully, but can not push it

Comment: I tried again, now I get this: $ git push origin main
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the process of repository creation, addition of a file, and remote synchronization. It seems like you are new to Git and this could help you get started.

Initialize an empty Git repository in the current directory:

```
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/user/
```

Create a file inside the repository:

```
$ cat > README << 'EOF'
> This is a sample README file.
> EOF
```

Add the file to the repository:

```
$ git add README
```

Commit the initial changes:

```
$ commit -m "Initial commit"
[master (root-commit) 3171739] Initial commit
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 README
```

Check the repository status:

```
$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Add a remote repository:

```
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/user/repo.git
```

Push changes to the remote repository:

```
$ git push -u origin master
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first part of your question, you seem to be using the wrong command.
`git push` is meant to push the changes you committed in your local repo to the remote.
If I understand correctly, you want to "push" the `P18.MovieApp` on GitHub. You can't just push a file directly to a remote.

These are the steps you need to follow:

- You want to add the `P18.MovieApp` file using `git add P18.MovieApp`, so that git will track this file.
- Next you *commit* your changes (`git commit -m "My commit message"`);
- And then you can *push* the changes you made to a remote (`git push`).

In the event that you don't have a remote set up for this repository, you will need to do

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:EXAMPLE_USERNAME/your-git-repository-name.git
git push -u origin main
```

(You should see these steps described in the page of the GitHub repository you created.)

Comment: You are correct. I thought I could upload it to Git hub by using "git push". I followed all the three steps, git add and git commit were successful, but git push does not work. I probably do not have a remote set up or something is messed up there (I set it up with tutorial). By the way - how am I supposed to upload files to GIT then? Exactly like I did it, by upload it manually (dropping them to git page?)

Comment: It seems like there's a confusion here. Git is the versioning tool that manage repositories, while GitHub is a service that provides Git repositories hosting. GitHub will act as your remote for your Git repository, so you will have a **local** and a **remote** copy of your repo.
I can't really tell what you mean by uploading to GIT in this context, and what is "git page" ?

Answer (score 1):

### Check remote URIs

In case that you can do your commits wihtout any problem but your push is the problem, first you need to check your `remote set up.`

Using the following line of code you can check your push and fetch URIs

```
git remote -v
```

> If nothing is displayed is because you haven't define a remote yet. In this case use the next line codes.

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/your-username/your-repository-name.git
git branch -M main
git push -u origin main
```

- ***I recommend to use the HTTPS direction if you are not familiarized with SSH***
- *You can find your HTTPS/SSH link to push, clicking in the "Clone" button (If you are using GitHub)*

---

If the `remote set up` are correct the problem could be in your configuration. Run the next code and search for `user.name` and `user.email`

```
git config -l
```

You can define your `user.name` and `user.email` with the next code:

```
git config --global user.name "FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME"
git config --global user.email "MY_NAME@example.com"
```

> *To avoid any posible "error" use your email and username from GitHub*

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who, like me, ran into this error:

```
On branch main
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
        modified:
```

This is what fixed it for me:

1. Save any folders you changed to your desktop (in my case, I had a folder with files and index.php)
2. Open your Finder (for Mac) or Windows explorer and delete the repository.
3. Re-clone the repository
4. Manually drag the files (not the folder) back into your project
5. Commit and push your changes.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).